# One domain points to another kubernetes ingress host domain using CNAME

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I have setup as below:

One kubernetes cluster with nginx ingress for deployment A. Ingress to deployment has configuration for host `example.com`. I want `abc.com` to point to `example.com`using CNAME but its always throwing SSL error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you need to use [Rewrite annotations](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/).

See the example below:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: rewrite
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: rewrite.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: http-svc
          servicePort: 80
        path: /something(/|$)(.*)
```

> In this ingress definition, any characters captured by (.*) will be 
>   assigned to the placeholder `$2`, which is then used as a parameter in
>   the rewrite-target annotation.    For example, the ingress definition
>   above will result in the following  rewrites:
>
> `- rewrite.bar.com/something` rewrites to `rewrite.bar.com/`
>
> `- rewrite.bar.com/something/` rewrites to `rewrite.bar.com/`
>
> `- rewrite.bar.com/something/new` rewrites to `rewrite.bar.com/new`

Please let me know if that helped.

EDIT:
More options:

- create additional `Ingresses`
- use HTTP (80) and generate SSL certificates

Comment: No this doesnt answer my question. If you read carefully, i have two different domains. Your answer has only one. Thanks though. I got to know something else :)

Comment: I see. You can create additional `Ingresses' in that case. Anyway,  please provide more details (yamls, configs) if that does not solves your problem. We need to know more about your use case in order to help you.

Comment: Thanks @OhHiMark. I was able to solve my problem by pointing it to HTTP (80) and generating SSL certs of that.Once SSL are placed for both domain, they worked. This was the only solution I found.

Comment: Good to hear that. Consider posting this as an answer or I could edit mine to include your info if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nginx ingress controller you can define this in the ingress in the same cluster where deployment a exists.

You will need to configure the nginx ingress controller to handle requests for both hosts lets say example.com and abc.com, you'll need to update the Ingress resource configuration. Here's a basic example of how you can configure it:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: your-service-name
            port:
              number: your-service-port
  - host: abc.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: your-service-name
            port:
              number: your-service-port
```

In this configuration:

- Replace `your-service-name` with the name of your Kubernetes service that corresponds to deployment A.
- Replace `your-service-port` with the port number of your service.
- Ensure that your DNS records for both example.com and abc.com point to the IP address of your Kubernetes cluster.

With this setup, the nginx ingress controller will route requests for both example.com and abc.com to the specified service. Make sure to apply this configuration to your Kubernetes cluster, and it should start routing traffic accordingly.